# List files by sorting them according to the EPOCH timestamp in filename

Tags: unix, command-line, unix-timestamp, ls

Below are some the files that are available in the directory
And epoch time is also a part of this file between # SYMBOLS

```
A#1444846033#1.txt
A#1444846037#1.txt
A#1444846041#1.txt
A#1444846057#1.txt
A#1444846061#1.txt
A#1444846045#1.txt
A#1444846065#1.txt
A#1444846049#1.txt
A#1444846069#1.txt
A#1444846053#1.txt
```

I would want to sort the above files  using the epoch time while listing them using command ls or ll
What are the flags used while using ll ?

Comment: The answer depends on the symbols outside the time stamp. Do you always have `A#` before and `#1.txt` after?

Comment: up.v.000945:losa.01.tns.17.elm.0#780200700103#1444852273#1.bin : This is the way the files are named

Comment: You did not mark constant parts of the names.

Comment: In all the filenames , the values between 2nd and 3rd # symbol is epoch time and i would like to sort the names according to that time (#1444852273#)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
 ls -1 | sort -t '#' -k 2
```

`ls -1` produces file list in one column. The following `sort` takes this list and sorts it by the second (`-k 2`) field using the `#` symbol (`-t '#'`) as the field separator.

Since your file name pattern includes neither special nor new line symbols, there should not be any problem until a very big number of files is placed in the same directory.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to explain how this will solve the problem.  In particular, you should point out the limitations of this approach, mainly concerning newlines in filenames, but also decimal rollover (though it's a long while until the next one, I do remember reaching 10 billion since Unix epoch).
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.